# What is the text appearance and style for Preference Activity

Tags: android

I have a Preference Activity which uses PreferenceScreen as one of the Preference.

Can you please tell me what is the text appearance and style that the PreferenceScreen (both the title text and the detail text)?

I would like to create an EditText field on a different activity which matches the exact same style.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For title:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

For summary:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

Comment: checking the last material design specs looks like the textappearance for title is 
             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"